# Cannot render any components with React-Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am working with version `3.0.0` of `react-router` and version `15.3.2` of `react/react-dom`.

My app is a simple one, rendering a small, red box. The component `App` is written as a class, as more will be added to it, though I'm sure I could have written it as a simple `const`, but that's beside the point. The app looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>App:</h1>
                <Home />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const Home = (props) =>
    <div>
        <p>This app renders a red box!</p>
        <div style={{background: 'red', width: 100, height: 100}}></div>
    </div>

render(
    <App></App>,
    document.getElementById('app')
)
```

However, when I try to setup an extremely simple routing, nothing renders at all! My code reads:

```
import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute} from 'react-router'

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>App:</h1>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const Home = (props) =>
    <div>
        <p>This app renders a red box!</p>
        <div style={{background: 'red', width: 100, height: 100}}></div>
    </div>

render(
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home}></IndexRoute>
        </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Why is nothing rendering? Am I misunderstanding `react-router` entirely?

Comment: I copy pasted your router code and it works perfectly fine for me. Are you getting any console errors? What does your index.html look like?

Comment: This is actually very interesting. I never had any console errors, and my html file is pretty barebones, with a `<div>` to input React code, and a `<script>` pointing to my bundled javascript file. I reconfigured my code so that my routing is done through my entry point `index.js` in my base folder, along side `node_modules`, my `index.html` file, and so on. Once I did that, everything seemed to render correctly. Could it be the switching of the routing from my `app.jsx` file to my `index.js` file that made a difference? I cannot pin-point why it wasn't working for me.